# Java equivalent of memcpy'ing a char[] to short

Tags: java, c++, arrays, kotlin, memcpy

In Java or Kotlin, what would be the equivalent of this C++ code:

```
char* data = new char[size]; 
//read file to this array

short version = 0;
memcpy(&version, data, 2);
```

I tried this:

```
//java equivalent of the kotlin code below
Integer.parseInt(String(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 0, 2)))

//kotlin:
data.copyOfRange(0, 2).concatToString().toInt()
```

but it doesn't work.

ByteBuffer doesn't work as well:

```
data[0] is 14
data[1] is 0
ByteBuffer.wrap(data).getShort() is 3584, memcpy is 14

data[2] is -28
data[3] is 45
data[4] is 0
data[5] is 0
ByteBuffer.wrap(data).getInt(2) is -466812928, memcpy is 11748
```

Comment: >ByteBuffer.wrap(data).getShort() is 3584, memcpy is 14< That's because C is usually little endian. Try `ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getShort();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ByteBuffer`:

```
byte[] data = new byte[size];
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
short version = buffer.getShort();
```

If needed you can also change the byte order

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't work the same way c++ code does. I've added some debug info in the question if you are interested.

Comment: So you change the byte order: `buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)`. If I do that and call `buffer.getShort()` followed by `buffer.getInt()`, I get 14 and 11748. The `getInt()` doesn't need a position if you call it directly after the call to `getShort()` because any getter that doesn't take a position reads from the current position and moves the position.